# List<PdfPCell> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, string, arraylist, arguments

I have set fo strings and I **need** to add them in to the **ArrayList** with the type **PdfPCell** in order to process them later with iText Library. Here is the code:

```
try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    scan.useDelimiter(",|" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    while(scan.hasNext()) {
        String id = scan.next();
        String txt1 = scan.next();
        String txt2 = scan.next();
        String txt3 = scan.next();

        // ArrayList with PdfPCell type
        List<PdfPCell> allCols = new ArrayList<PdfPCell>();
        allCols.add(id);
        allCols.add(txt1);
        allCols.add(txt2);
        allCols.add(txt3);

        System.out.println(allCols);
    }
    scan.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Error:**
`The method add(PdfPCell) in the type List<PdfPCell> is not applicable for the arguments (String)`

I'm stuck here. How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List `allCols` is `PdfPCell` typed. you can not add `String` object into it. As `String` is not sub class of `PdfPCell` :), so it should raised compile time error .

you should simply create object of `PdfPCell` add into it.

```
List<PdfPCell> allCols = new ArrayList<PdfPCell>();
allCols.add(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(id));
allCols.add(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(txt1));
...
```

Comment: You are right, but I need to apply strings to the ArrayList<PdfPCell> or relate them somehow. That's why I created this question.

Comment: answer updated... See PdfCell can be anything, like - Phrase, Paragraph,... any Element. You can create required object and add it.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is a `String` and cannot be converted/type casted to your custom type `PdfPCell` directly. Even if `PdfPCell` only has 1 String instance variable.

To solve this, you can add a *String argument constructor* to your `PdfPCell` or better add create a factory.

```
List<PdfPCell> allCols = new ArrayList<PdfPCell>();
allCols.add(Factory.getPdfCell(id));//or
allCols.add(new PdfPCell(id));
```